# I want to build a song recognition website

Tags: php, database

I was thinking about building a website for song recognition (something similar to midomi.com but much more simple):

User uploads a MP3 or posts a link to a Youtube video and the website will tell him (for free) the name of the track, artist and other info - basically all the stuff that should be in the MP3's ID3 tag.

The biggest problem is how should I recognize the song? I don't plan writing the algorithm myself (I can't spend that much time on something I want to offer for free :-)).

I know that e.g. Winamp uses the Gracenote database http://www.gracenote.com/ for MP3 identification.
Can you do the same using PHP - by calling some their remote method that searches the database for a match with the provided file or its "footprint"?

Or can you suggest any other databases or tools?

I found someone used Gracenote in PHP here: http://www.phpfreaks.com/forums/index.php?topic=240930.0
But that's basically just editing the texts in the tags. What about song recognition?

Comment: Gracenote does not seem to be that good. I tried it to recognize this one: `laa-laa-la, la-la-la-laa, la, la-la`, but it failed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- This article should get you started with the comparison of audio samples:
  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acoustic_fingerprint
- MusicBrainz offers a webservice you can query for track information:
  http://musicbrainz.org/doc/XMLWebService

  - They also offer information on audio fingerprinting:
    http://musicbrainz.org/doc/AudioFingerprint

Comment: Wow, never heard of musicbrainz before! Their website looks promising, the downside is that on Wikipedia they say that Musicbrainz database is about 8 times smaller than Gracenote. :-(

Comment: @Marek: Yes, but from my experience it's still very good though. You can also help to expand the database with your website. Good Luck!

Answer (score 2):

An MP3 file would use `ID3 Tags` to identify the song. The `Title` and `Artist` name are embedded in the song. `ID3 tags` can also include the `ISRC` number (International Standard Music Number) for identification. Grace note is primarily concerned about CD Identification, *.cda files in the CD, and may be MCDI (Music CD Identifier).

Answer (score 0):

There is a fingerprint [recognition service](https://docs.acrcloud.com/docs/acrcloud/tutorials/identify-audio-custom-content/) with api. It has clients for different languages and [free](https://ap-console.acrcloud.com/pricing) for test apps.